# Htaccess file giving me HTTP Error 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Im trying to write a htaccess file and let my sitemaps through so they dont get re-directed/re-writed. So they actually go the correct url if that makes sense. This is what I have so far...

```
RewriteEngine on
```

RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L]

```
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap_index.xml [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/track-sitemap.xml
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} facebookexternalhit/1.1|Facebot|Googlebot|bingbot|Googlebot-Mobile|Baiduspider|Yahoo|YahooSeeker|DoCoMo|Twitterbot|TweetmemeBot|Twikle|Netseer|Daumoa|SeznamBot|Ezooms|MSNBot|Exabot|MJ12bot|sogou\sspider|YandexBot|bitlybot|ia_archiver|proximic|spbot|ChangeDetection|NaverBot|MetaJobBot|magpie-crawler|Genieo\sWeb\sfilter|Qualidator.com\sBot|Woko|Vagabondo|360Spider|ExB\sLanguage\sCrawler|AddThis.com|aiHitBot|Spinn3r|BingPreview|GrapeshotCrawler|CareerBot|ZumBot|ShopWiki|bixocrawler|uMBot|sistrix|linkdexbot|AhrefsBot|archive.org_bot|SeoCheckBot|TurnitinBot|VoilaBot|SearchmetricsBot|Butterfly|Yahoo!|Plukkie|yacybot|trendictionbot|UASlinkChecker|Blekkobot|Wotbox|YioopBot|meanpathbot|TinEye|LuminateBot|FyberSpider|Infohelfer|linkdex.com|Curious\sGeorge|Fetch-Guess|ichiro|MojeekBot|SBSearch|WebThumbnail|socialbm_bot|SemrushBot|Vedma|alexa\ssite\saudit|SEOkicks-Robot|Browsershots|BLEXBot|woriobot|AMZNKAssocBot|Speedy|oBot|HostTracker|OpenWebSpider|WBSearchBot|FacebookExternalHit [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/$1? [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/%1? [NC,L]

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
     RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

     RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Im getting it for the sitemaps, when i check google webmaster tools

Answer (score 0):

The last one RewriteRule will cause an infinite redirection.
Add some RewriteCond, or beter - remove it because it's pointless.

Comment: sorry this is my first time writing a htaccess, do you have any suggestion

Comment: I need the last RewriteRule as all my routes are directed there, because im using angularjs

Comment: Well, then you need to add some RewriteCond that excluding index.php from the matching. Or modify RewriteRule regex for the same reason.

Comment: do you have any suggestions really new to this, been on it for two weeks with no luck..... I thought the [L] in the first re-write prevents furthur rules

Comment: Add something like this before last one RewtiteRule: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/index.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90469/discussion-between-user3355603-and-eugeny).

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule for sitemap is causing infinite looping:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap_index.xml [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/track-sitemap.xml
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1 [L]
```

as it is rewriting sitemap URLs to same URL.

Change first rule to below rule to ignore all rewrite rule for sitemap URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap_index\.xml [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/track-sitemap\.xml
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: ok provide full URL that your webserver is getting and you must provide exact error message from Apache error.log

Comment: umm not sure how to access my error logs...new to all this

Comment: Ask your server admin or someone who has access to host and can check Apache error.log

Comment: Really stuck on this one